# PostgreSQL + Rails connection troubleshooting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rails-postgresql

I've used this site a bunch over the past three years or so...this is my first post :D

But enough of the useless banter and on to the business at hand.

---

I will start with the approach/problem, the error, and then a trace/log of the error.

Then I will go over what I've done so far to best this problem, some odd things I've noticed, and what I think might be causing it.

---

**APPROACH/PROBLEM:**

I was recently added to the back-end development team for a mobile app, and before I implement any new features I have to get the product up and running on my local machine...

(in app directory) rails s

=> Booting WEBrick

=> Rails 3.1.0.rc4 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000

=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server

[2011-09-14 19:11:59] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1

[2011-09-14 19:11:59] INFO  ruby 1.8.7 (2009-06-12) [universal-darwin10.0]

[2011-09-14 19:11:59] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=35031 port=3000

So all of this looks fine for now, but when I attempt to access the page on a browser...

---

**ERROR:**

(browser page title): Action Controller:Exception caught

PGError

fe_sendauth: no password supplied

---

**TRACE/LOG**

(continued from last line on terminal in the first section)

cache error: No server available

/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/dalli-1.0.5/lib/dalli/ring.rb:45:in `server_for_key'

/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/dalli-1.0.5/lib/dalli/client.rb:239:in `perform'

/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/dalli-1.0.5/lib/dalli/client.rb:60:in `get'

/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rack-cache-1.0.3/lib/rack/cache/metastore.rb:320:in `read'

/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rack-cache-1.0.3/lib/rack/cache/metastore.rb:30:in `lookup'

/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rack-cache-1.0.3/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:165:in `lookup'

/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rack-cache-1.0.3/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:65:in `call!'

/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rack-cache-1.0.3/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:50:in `call'

/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.3.2/lib/rack/deflater.rb:13:in `call'

/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.1.0.rc4/lib/rails/rack/content_length.rb:16:in `call'

/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.1.0.rc4/lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:14:in `call'

/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.3.2/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:59:in `service'

/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/httpserver.rb:104:in `service'

/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/httpserver.rb:65:in `run'

/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:173:in `start_thread'

/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:162:in `start'

/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:162:in `start_thread'

/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:95:in `start'

/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:92:in `each'

/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:92:in `start'

/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:23:in `start'

/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:82:in `start'

/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.3.2/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:13:in `run'

/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.3.2/lib/rack/server.rb:265:in `start'

/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.1.0.rc4/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:70:in `start'

/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.1.0.rc4/lib/rails/commands.rb:54

/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.1.0.rc4/lib/rails/commands.rb:49:in `tap'

/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.1.0.rc4/lib/rails/commands.rb:49

script/rails:6:in `require'

script/rails:6

cache: [GET /] pass

Dalli::Server#connect localhost:11211

localhost:11211 failed (count: 0)

I can give out the full trace from the browser as well, but I don't want this post to get TOO wordy.

So this is the dilemma!

---

**What I've Done:**

The simple solutions(listed below) haven't made any difference.

The pg gem installed correctly(after including the path manually)

I fixed the pg_hba.conf file to allow trust(ed) connections.

I can connect to a postgres db through the pgadmin3 tool and through the terminal.

---

**Huh?:**

Running the server on a different port doesn't make any difference, although if I try to connect to one of the ports reserved for my postgresql db, the connection is busy(I can post that error log as well, if needed).

If I try to access a non-existent page from the app...like users/explode or signin/signout, the error is the same. The terminal log does show the " [GET /'var'] pass " each time, though.

---

**Thoughts:**

My best guess is that the problem is from the connection still expecting a password, since there is a pass - word at the end of " [GET /'var'] pass "

OR

That the pg db is being run on a different server and the app doesn't like me trying to run it on my local machine.

I'm hoping your guess is better than mine.

---

If you managed to make it though this post, kudos. It's greatly appreciated. 
If you manage to come up with a solution, somehow, I will be eternally gracious.

Regards,

~Ryan Johnson(RyeGuyHead)

Answer (score 4):

Either change your pg_hba.conf to

```
local   all         all                               trust
host    all         all         127.0.0.1/32          trust
host    all         all         ::1/128               trust
```

Or replace `trust` to `md5` and specify the password in `database.yml`

Comment: Awesome!

My pg_hba.conf file was identical to the on you posted, but when I changed the database.yml file to include the password and switched "trust" to "md5" I got a different error.

But this is one I should be able to fix...

Many thanks